# How to implement a Shared Kernel (DDD) in .Net properly

Tags: .net, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have a legacy app I am redesigning because it's what we call a "ball of mudd" at this point, no layering or SOC at all.  The team is used to working modularly, meaning there is a team that works on "training", "Job Opportunities", one that works on a module managing "Duty Planning (military)".  We have one website exposing these areas to our clients as a portal of services, one database and a few external apps we service.

Im doing well redesigning most of the layers except how to partition the domain properly (I should mention at this point that we are using .Net 4.0).  My original thought was that these were bounded contexts because of the way they were working, they really seemed to have different sets of users, but I believe now the reality is people who use this site may and do use many areas at once.  Sure, some groups ONLY use one service exclusively, but a lot use several.  The goal of the site is one-stop management of "members".  Between the modules we have classes unique to the module and then we have some shared classes, for example, the concept of a member is known and used by all modules.  Member is actually a core concept, the site adds value by tracking member's information in all these areas at once.  That's basically it, a few closely related but separate areas in the system and a shared area.  I hope that is clear enough to answer the question I have.

I am thinking I would still have a shared kernel, even if these are not bounded contexts, for the common entities and shared domain interfaces such as a generic repository interface.  Would it be wise to put all the common code (generic repository, core domain model, shared kernel etc) into the same namespace or namespace hierarchy and should I isolate this namespace in it's own assembly?  Likewise, would I then break out each area ("training", "Opportunities"...) into their own assemblies or is it better to have them all in one assembly and logically partition them by namespace.  On one hand, it's a bit easier to see the modules physically partitioned, but I am worried about situations where two modules need to work together to solve a problem.  How would they communicate and keep things acyclic (through services in the application layer I am guessing).

so (summary of options):

Domain.Model (dll)
  -- Domain.Model.Core
     -- Kernel (shared entities and core domain model)
     -- RepositoryFramework
     -- etc...
  -- Domain.Model.Training
  -- Domain.Model.Opportunities
  ...

or

Domain.Model.Core

Domain.Model.Training (dll)

Domain.Model.Opportunities (dll)
(how do training and opportunities work together?)

Thank you very much for your time,

Answer (score 3):

In case of physical layout, I would put everything (the whole domain model) in one assembly. Using separate assemblies does not give you any benefit while it complicates things and increases compilation time.

On the other hand, if there is a risk that some developers use inappropriate classes (those who belong to other modules/contexts), it may be wise to split the logic into a common assembly (core domain, shared kernel) and assemblies specific to each module/context.

In the case of the logical layout (namespaces) I would give each part a separate namespace (for example DomainModel.Core, DomainModel.Training). Sometimes it is wise to go one step further and put each Aggregate into its own namespace. It prevents accidental crossing of the aggregate boundaries since it requires a separate 'using' directive.

Hope that makes sense.